# TortoiseHg RevSet Query to see Branch Lineage

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

In TortoiseHg is it possible to write a revset query that would show only the changesets involved in branching?  More specifically I'd like to see the the first revision of every branch, it's direct parent, and the current head of each branch.

My goal here is to see a concise picture of all the branching activity that's happening in our repo without all the intermediate check-ins.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to write a revset query that would show only the changesets involved in branching?

Yes

(I use my [Assembla repo](https://www.assembla.com/code/seeker/mercurial/nodes) with single named branch as example and check-point for you in the following examples)

1. the first revision of every branch

`hg log -r "branch(Cleanup)" -l 1` or `hg log -r "min(branch(Cleanup))"` or `hg log -r "first(branch(Cleanup))"`

```
changeset:   58:f7f288c9e72b
branch:      Cleanup
parent:      55:acadd1e83fba
```

1. it's direct parent

`hg log -r "parents(min(branch(Cleanup)))"` or `hg log -r "p1(min(branch(Cleanup)))"` or `hg log -r "min(branch(Cleanup))^"`

```
changeset:   55:acadd1e83fba
```

1. the current head of each branch

`hg heads Cleanup` or `hg log -r "head() and (branch(Cleanup))"` or `hg log -r "heads(branch(Cleanup))"`

```
changeset:   67:67608168d4b3
branch:      Cleanup
tag:         tip
```